# Parallel execution of functions in android main class

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my app I have 6 `Arrays` which should be updated each time my main activity starts. They all updated with main thread now and this leads to degradation in my app speed. Here is my `dbUpdate()` function:

```
private void dbUpdate(){
        dateDB = getDateValues();
        valueDB = getValues();
        catDB = getCatValues();
        catIndexDB = getCatIndex();
        catExpenseDB = getCatExpense();
        catLimitDB = getCatLimits();
}
```

These arrays have no dependency on eath other and I want to update them 6 parallel thread. I read [this](http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-multi-threading-in-android-with-handler-class/28175) article and tried to put each array `get` function in a `Runnable`:

```
  Runnable run6 = new Runnable(){
      @Override
      public void run(){
            catLimitDB = getCatLimits();
      }
  };
```

So now I have six `Runnable` and one `Handler` and I changed my `dbUpdate()` function:

```
private void dbUpdate(){
        hand.post(run1);
        hand.post(run2);
        hand.post(run3);
        hand.post(run4);
        hand.post(run5);
        hand.post(run6);
}
```

But when I run my app I feel no difference. Can someone help me with this? And I should mention that this is my first experience with `multithread` programming.

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely sure but if you're putting them all on one handler, they'll all be on that new thread and take just as long. The only difference being that they're not on the UI thread. Tell me if I'm wrong, but I'd go for 6 different threads and see if that helps

Comment: where do these values come from?

Comment: @Yorrd ok I give it a try thank you

Comment: @mmlooloo They come from SharedPrefrences keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really want to run them in parrallel you might do something like this:

```
new Thread(run1).start();
new Thread(run2).start();
new Thread(run3).start();
..
```

with the handler.post you add your jobs to a queue to the hanler - and your handler might be configured to run on the UI thread - so this might not be what you want.

Comment: Well, that seems reasonable and actually now I feel some differences in my app but I encountered a new problem, in this case sometimes some of my arrays has not been updated and the rest of the code is executed. This leads to NullPointerException. Do you have any idea how I can handle this?

Comment: that depends on your code and should be a separate question. if this answer solves your problem please accept it so this question is "closed"